# What is this violet colored spread in the sky?

Tags: identify-this, auroras

Today on my way from Madison, WI, USA  to Minneapolis, MN, USA on highway I94 I saw sky light up with violet color. Timestamp on my picture is at 6:48 PM. It's very strange. I do not think it was northern lights, too soon to hop on alien story. I know this could be due to some lights, but it was so bright and spread across such a large area, its stuck in my head. I am attaching pictures. Not very good quality as I was driving.

Let me know if you guys have any guesses.  [image][image]

Comment: Aliens, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @NeanDerThal - that would only be true if it was accompanied by a loud humming sound and his car and all electical devices in it suddenly lost power. Otherwise, no. The *real* reason is much simpler. Minneapolis is the former home of the former rock star formerly known as Prince, who was famously associated with the color purple. This is just a haunting. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: [foto of the same kind of sky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVjXp.jpg) Wisconsin today too same road and same time

Comment: See also (with a similar image): [2022-07-23: BBC News - Eerie glow in sky confuses Australian town and outs cannabis farm](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-62261094)

Comment: Interesting question, but not worth the risk of taking the photos while driving :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A greenhouse!

I know, but bear with me. Many on Twitter / Instagram snapped photos of similar lights, in recent times and in various places, and one of the sources was tracked down:

> It turns out the mystery light came from a new, high-tech,
> 85,000-square-foot greenhouse on 76th Street near Hanna Lake Avenue
> southwest of Dutton. The glow was the result of special purple LED
> lights that can adjust to different spectrums to fit plants' needs.

Sources:

- [Purple glow in sky traced to greenhouse lights](https://www.woodtv.com/1622570301)
- [Why Was the Sky Purple](https://www.woodtv.com/weather/bill-s-blog/purple-sky-likely-caused-by-greenhouse/1621496691)
- [Alien invasion? Not so much. Purple sky came from greenhouse lights](https://www.wzzm13.com/article/news/local/alien-invasion-not-so-much-purple-sky-came-from-greenhouse-lights/69-618103696)

It's been reported in several places around the USA and [Australia](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-62261094), and so far at least, always comes from greenhouses with these LEDs.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this specific greenhouse in Dutton, Michigan is the source of the light seen by the OP, as it's over 200 miles away from OP's starting point, in the opposite direction.  But it does lead one to suspect that OP could have seen a different greenhouse of a similar type.

Comment: See the final sentence, where I quoted from the last article which points out it's been noted in many places around the country

Comment: @NateEldredge updated a bit to clarify

Comment: I think I was confused by your phrase "snapped photos of *it*".  I made another edit to try to clarify further. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @NateEldredge looks good!

Comment: I get an ‘access denied’ page on the third link (the whole site, actually) – locally restricted, or just server bugout?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have the same issue - I’m in the UK. Perhaps an EU restriction?

Comment: Wow, the overall efficiency must be pretty bad if so much light is sent to the atmosphere. And as an amateur astronomer, I'd be really angry at such a disturbing light source.

Comment: You could add this [similar question, image, and area](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/74utez/seen_in_the_sky_over_wisconsin_last_night/) asked a year ago on reddit.

Comment: @Tim No matter where you come down on the EU, the odds that they decided to restrict a single local USA news site by intercepting HTTPS traffic and somehow translating it to a 403 response .. are vanishingly low. More likely the site is georestricting its users to prevent spending lots of money on bandwidth serving those outside of its core audience.... or it's just having a technically bad day.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit To clarify, I meant a restriction on the part of the site owners for EU users, possibly because of GDPR. They would not be the only site to do that.

Comment: @Tim: Ah, well that's more likely ;) (BTW hi from Wollaton)

Comment: These kinds of lights tend to be associated with a certain farming activity where locality has a strong impact on legality :)

Comment: Wow. Very interesting. Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: @Tim You are right that the site is restricting access from EEA countries. It is accessible from non-EEA European countries like Switzerland, Russia or Serbia.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it would be great if someone could transfer the link to archive.org so everyone can see!

Comment: @Tim it's not on archive.org, but is in the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.wzzm13.com/article/news/local/alien-invasion-not-so-much-purple-sky-came-from-greenhouse-lights/69-618103696)